# Anyone know of a Wi-Fi light switch that works with Linux?

Tags: smart-home, linux

I'm looking for a single or dual Wi-Fi light switch that I can activate with Linux. It needs to fit a standard 2-gang switch box and/or include a trim plate that covers a 2-gang box. Anyone know of such a thing? I can't tell from the selection on Amazon if any of these work without installing some smartphone app. I'm based in the US.

At this point, I'd settle for a micro-remote controlled switch, if nothing else, and then just wire a Raspberry Pi to the contacts.

The current switches I have in the gang box now are like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0006DNQWK). I suppose there is a little room for a wider switch – like I just found a [Z-Wave switch](https://smile.amazon.com/Z-Wave-Switch-Repeater-SmartThings-Inovelli/dp/B076LS3SLY) , but they don't list with dimensions of the switch so I don't know it will fit in the box next to the "regular" switch.

Comment: Relevant: [Is there a way to control my lights from my Linux desktop?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/2150/is-there-a-way-to-control-my-lights-from-my-linux-desktop) (but that question doesn't specifically ask for *switches*)

Comment: For the Z-Wave switch you mentioned, they do list "package dimensions" in the Amazon listing of 5 x 3.8 x 3 inches . What I usually do in a case like that is to find a website for the company making the component, and search for that specific item. You might be able to find a drawing giving exact dimensions. Or send an email or phone call to their support contacts. 

You could also post a question to those that have purchased one on the Amazon itself, and/or post a question to via the Amazon Innovelli storefront (click on the blue Innovelli link on the ad).

Comment: This link from their site shows actual dimensions of a switch: https://inovelli.com/shop/smart-light-switches/z-wave-toggle-switch-on-off-w-scenes-repeater/

Please do your own research to make sure it is the same one or similar enough.

Comment: If you're OK with having to do the initial setup with a phone, then Belkin WeMo Insight switches work with Linux (specifically with Home Assistant running on a Raspberry Pi 3). Not "out of the box" though, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the tips everyone. @AaronF what is the Home Assistant? A python script? compiled binary?

Comment: @WillT. [Home Assistant](http://homeassistant.io/) is written in Python and has plugins for many different devices. These are all exposed in a similar way: at a most basic level, there are 'sensors' and 'switches', then 'automations' are scripts which execute upon a change in sensor value and can operate switches. I can put more detail in an answer, hopefully later today...

Answer (score 2):

paraphrased from my answer [here](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/3131/controlling-wifi-switches-from-physical-switch):

You could use the [Belkin Wemo Light Switch](http://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-F7C030/), if you can find one (apparently Belkin aren't making new ones any more).

The initial configuration has to be done using the Belkin Wemo phone app, but once it's connected to your wireless network then you can forget the app and use [Home Assistant](https://www.home-assistant.io/) instead.

I personally run Home Assistant on a Raspberry Pi 3 and have some Wemo switches and light bulbs. They're automatically detected with no extra configuration required.

---

Another option, which I saw the other day in [this answer](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/3232/does-a-battery-powered-light-switch-exist-to-control-a-smart-plug/3233#3233), is a [batteryless Bluetooth Low Energy wall switch](https://www.easyfit-controls.com/easyfit-for-bluetooth-lighting-systems/).
I can't find any to actually buy online, at the time of writing this answer, but they appear to be a good generic solution: pressing the switch generates enough power to send a BLE packet.
 
You'll still need something like Home Assistant to listen out for that event and act upon it, though.

Comment: Thanks. Just checked back on this post as I haven't found a simple solution yet. It's hard to fathom with all the Alexa and Google incorporated into these gizmos that none of them support a Linux compatible interface.

Comment: It's crazy, isn't it? Every manufacturer wants to get you into their walled garden and eschews interoperability. I have to move house soon and have been looking again at the available options. There's still nothing that ticks all my boxes. I think I'm going to end up buying some Pi-compatible relays that can safely switch 240V...

Comment: Ran across this today. Looks promising: https://openhomeautomation.net/control-a-lamp-remotely-using-the-esp8266-wifi-chip