# Does a battery-powered light switch exist to control a smart plug?

Tags: smart-plugs, smart-lights

I have an apartment with no light switch or ceiling light for the living room. I have a lamp that's plugged into the wall. Because it's an apartment, I can't just install a physical light switch.

All I would like is to connect my lamp to a smart plug and have that smart plug be controlled by a switch that I could mount to the wall with command strips. If I have to replace the batteries for the switch every so often, that's fine with me.

The problem is, searching for "smart light switch" or "light switch for wifi plug" or "switch for smart plug" doesn't yield any results I want. Does such a thing exist? And if so, how could I better phrase my search query to find this?

Comment: You could use a Philips Hue lamp or Philips Hue smart plug https://www2.meethue.com/en-us/p/hue-smart-plug/046677552343 and then control it with a wireless switch https://www2.meethue.com/en-gb/friends-of-hue/switches or tap switch https://www2.meethue.com/en-us/p/hue-tap-switch/046677473365

Answer (score 3):

I guess, this solution is even better.

https://www.easyfit-controls.com/easyfit-for-bluetooth-lighting-systems/

BLE switch module that doesn't need power at all because it harvest the energy from pushing the switch. 
It's freely configurable but it isn't really a ready-to-go setup for any smart plug as it requires manual NFC interfacing. Probably there are similiar solutions with more user-friendly configuration options.

Answer (score 3):

Insteon:

Single wireless [Wallswitch](https://www.smarthome.com/insteon-2342-242-mini-remote-switch.html) remote.

[Plug in module](https://www.smarthome.com/lamplinc-insteon-2457d2-plug-in-lamp-dimmer-module-dual-band-2-pin.html) w/dim.

Those are the only two parts you need.  They can be linked (programmed) manually.

Adding a hub adds control from a smartphone and makes programming easier (although a simple two device system as above is very easy manually anyway).

There are also multi-button wireless switches and many other options.

Insteon is always less expensive to purchase in starter packs, and multi-packs.  They also have 20/25/30% off sales with regularity (if I was placing bets, Labor Day weekend will be the next).  Smarthome.com and Insteon.com are related companies (both have same street address), as such smarthome always has better deals than any other dealer but sometimes it’s best to wait for the next sale.  In a hurry? Menards usually has many items in stock in stores.

Insteon is also available in a variety of international versions, but it’s actually hard to view international product. (Your internet IP determines which products are offered to you.)